# Computation of trace

Tags: tensors, multilinear-algebra

> Show that the trace on any pair of indices is a well-deﬁned
>   linear map from $T^{k+1}_{l+1} (V )$ to $T^k_l(V )$.

I don't have any clue..

Comment: You should give your definition of the trace, because there are multiple (equivalent) ways to define it. In your case it is probably defined in terms of components, and hence to show it is well-defined you should show that it doesn't depend on the choice of basis.

Comment: Thanks @HenryT.Horton. I guess I am stuck at a more rudimentary place. I simply don't know what is the linear transformation isomorphic to $T_l^k$.

Answer (score 1):

Let me just clarify a couple of things.

Your question is exactly Exercise $2.2$ of Lee's *Riemannian Manifolds: An Introduction to Curvature*. In that text, $T^k_l(V)$ denotes the collection of all $\binom{k}{l}$-tensors ($k$-covariant, $l$-contravariant) which are multilinear maps $(V^*)^l\times V^k \to \mathbb{R}$. Lee defines the trace of $F \in T^{k+1}_{l+1}(V)$ (on it's last covariant and contravariant factors) to be the the element $\operatorname{tr} F \in T^k_l(V)$ given by $$\operatorname{tr} F(\omega^1, \dots, \omega^l, X_1, \dots, X_k) := \operatorname{trace}F(\omega^1, \dots, \omega^l, \cdot, X_1, \dots, X_k, \cdot)$$ where $F(\omega^1, \dots, \omega^l, \cdot, X_1, \dots, X_k, \cdot) \in T^1_1(V) \cong \operatorname{End}(V)$ and $\operatorname{trace}$ indicates the trace of this endomorphism. In terms of a basis, $$(\operatorname{tr} F)^{j_1 \dots j_l}_{i_1 \dotsm i_k} = F^{j_1 \dots j_l m}_{i_1 \dots i_k m}$$ where Einstein notation is being used, so the right hand side is actually a sum over the index $m$. There is nothing special about using the last covariant and contravariant factors/indices though, you can use any pair and obtain a map $T^{k+1}_{l+1}(V) \to T^k_l(V)$ given by the trace in an analogous way. The exercise asks you to verify that, for any pair of indices, this map is well-defined and linear.